# Add Button is not responding to clicks...and even logcat doesn't show the error message?

Tags: android, kotlin

Add button is not responding to any of the clicks i treid everything but its not just responding...my code for the activity and the layout is below

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add)

    val binding: ActivityAddBinding = ActivityAddBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    val title = binding.etTitle
    val author = binding.etAuthor
    val pages = binding.etNoOfPages
    val addBtn = binding.btnAdd

    addBtn.setOnClickListener {
        Log.e("Button Clicked","ButtonResponded/NotResponded")
        Toast.makeText(this,"Add Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        //val myDB = MyDatabaseHelper(this)           
      //myDB.addBook(title.text.toString(),author.text.toString(),Integer.parseInt(pages.toString()))
    }
}
```

Layoutfile........

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="24dp"
    tools:context=".AddActivity">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_add"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:text="@string/add"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/et_no_of_pages" />
```

PLease help

Comment: Here is the Android View Binding official Doc usage link for reference.  https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding#setup

I just copied above given instructions code in my project and it's working fine, Also, it's same as your code.

Have you added bindingsFeature in your gradle file ?

Comment: @hari yup added the build feature

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove your existing `setContentView` line and add `setContentView(binding.getRoot())` at the end of your onCreate() method.

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
val binding: ActivityAddBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_add)
```

instead of

```
val binding: ActivityAddBinding = ActivityAddBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
```

and since you set your content view by calling `DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)` you no longer need to use `setContentView(R.layout.activity_add)`

full `onCreate()` should look like this

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    val binding: ActivityAddBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_add)
    val title = binding.etTitle
    val author = binding.etAuthor
    val pages = binding.etNoOfPages
    val addBtn = binding.btnAdd

    addBtn.setOnClickListener {
        Log.e("Button Clicked","ButtonResponded/NotResponded")
        Toast.makeText(this,"Add Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        //val myDB = MyDatabaseHelper(this)           
      //myDB.addBook(title.text.toString(),author.text.toString(),Integer.parseInt(pages.toString()))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The better way to inflate a `View` with databinding in `Activity` class is

```java
    binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_add)
```